# Trouble opening XAMPP files with localhost after using manually installed Apache server

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I installed Apache manually and got the localhost to work.  Now I have decided to use XAMPP instead of the manual install, and I am having trouble opening XAMPP files via localhost.  I can only open them as " file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/applications.html ".  Do I still have to do something to reconfigure my localhost from the manual Apache install to XAMPP?

Thanks

Comment: Because the two instances have a different web document root you will need to stop the manual install of Apache and start the one in XAMPP so there are no port conflicts.

Comment: Hi, yeah, I disabled the manual install already, but I think I am seeing that it is still on port 80 (it says "httpd.exe", which I think refers to the manual install).  So, I am going to try editing the httpd file in XAMPP Apache to a different port.

Comment: Seems to have worked.  Thanks for your reply!